# Scanf inside a function possible?

Tags: c

Question but maybe something very simple I overlook here. I am trying to put a scanf function inside a function. Is this possible like in the following example?
When I try to do this, Main does not seem to receive the value passed back from makechoice and the final number is always 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int makechoice(int choice) {
  printf("Make a choice\n");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  return choice;
};

int main() {
  int choice;

  makechoice(choice);
  printf("The number that the function makechoice returned is %d", choice);

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: The return value from `makechoice` is being ignored. Also, passing uninitialized values to it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to call `scanf` inside a function. In fact, it wouldn't make sense or be legal to call `scanf` _outside` a function.

However, C function arguments are passed by *value*. This means that the changes made to `choice` in `makechoice` are just to that function argument. They have no bearing on the `choice` in `main`.

You have returned that value from `makechoice`, but never use that returned value in `main`.

You may be looking for something more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int make_choice() {
    int temp;
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    return temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int choice = makechoice();
    printf("The number that the function makechoice returned is %d", choice);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major approaches you can take.  Rather than a verbose description, I'll just give some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
makechoice1(void)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Make a choice\n");
    if( scanf("%d", &choice) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return choice;
}

int
makechoice2(int *choice)
{
    printf("Make a choice\n");
    if( scanf("%d", choice) != 1 ){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int choice

    choice = makechoice1();
    printf("The number that the function returned is %d\n", choice);
    if( makechoice2(&choice) ){
        fprintf(stderr, "The function failed\n");
    } else {
        printf("The number that the function returned is %d\n", choice);
    }
    return 0;
};
```